# React native app freezes when syncing 10 API calls

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I've been working on React Native app with Redux state management. In this app, Syncing happens every 1 minute. I hit 10 API calls each and every time.
Recently I've noticed app freezes in the **Android** app on the following conditions altogether.
1. When connected to mobile data.
2. When coming from the background.
3. And when sync API hits.

When these 3 scenarios happen all together, the app freezes for some seconds.

```
function* syncAPICalls(action, sample = undefined) {
let sampleData = settings;
try {
    yield* makeDevicesCall({});
    yield* makeDashboardNotificationCall({});
    if (isValidElement(sampleData)) {
        sampleData = sample;
    } else {
        sampleData = yield call(sampleApiCall1);
    }

    yield* sampleFunc1({ param: param});
    yield* sampleFunc2({ param: param});
    yield* sampleFunc3({ param: param});
    yield* sampleFunc4({ param: param});
    yield* sampleFunc5({ param: param});
    yield* sampleFunc6({ param: param});
    let phoneNo;
    if (isValidElement(phone)) {
        phoneNo = phone;
    } else {
        let sampleData2 = yield call(sampleApiCall2);
        phoneNo = sampleData2.contact_no;
    }
    yield* sampleFunc7({ param: param});
    yield* sampleFunc8({ param: param});
} catch (e) {
    if (__DEV__) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

}

I've renamed everything like a sample. Each **`sampleFunction`** will update the reducer using **`put`** method.

When I removed the Sync operations, the app works smoother and when in the foreground also sync is smoother.

Only when coming from background, mobile data, sync freezes.

I can assure you that sync is calling only once. And all API is getting success response.

**Verison**

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9
```

Am I doing something wrong?. Kindly give me some ideas of what went wrong, Thanks.

Comment: could you find any solution? I have same problem

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?